# How to redirect for Next.js middleware sub-directory?

Tags: javascript, next.js

I would like to redirect users in my middleware. However, Next.js middleware behaves inconsistently. If I place the middleware in `/pages/_middleware.ts` the redirect will work. If I place it in `/pages/api/_middleware.ts` the redirect will not work.

```
// /pages/_middleware.ts
export function middleware() {
  return NextResponse.redirect(
    `http://example.com`
  );
}
```

```
// /pages/api/_middleware.ts
export function middleware() {
  return NextResponse.redirect(
    `http://example.com`
  );
}
```

---

**Update:**

I did a test on a fresh project for `/api`. The user will be redirected if they direst navigate to the route `/api/hello`. However, when the request is made via code redirect will fail. I would like to add a redirect guard at the api level but this doesn't seem possible with `_middleware`.

```
fetch(
  `/api/hello`,
  {
    credentials: 'same-origin',
    method: 'POST',
  }
);
```

Comment: These examples redirect correctly on my end using Next.js 12.1.4. Are there any error messages in the console when accessing `/pages/api` itself or any of its sub-directories? Does each sub-directory contain its own `_middleware` file as well?

Comment: No errors here but I am on `12.1.0`. I didn't have any other `_middleware` files aside from my tests. I could also try having multiple in the test to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: @MarkG Just to confirm. You were able to navigate on `/pages/api/_middleware.ts`? I haven't been able to reproduce this. I am not on a fresh project however.

Comment: I was able to navigate to `http://localhost:3000/api` where the middleware correctly intercepted the request and performed a redirect. Are you literally appending "_middleware" to the URL in the browser's address bar?

Comment: I was able to reproduce a successful redirect in the `api` directory on a fresh project. It may be the case that Next.js _middleware doesn't play well with another lib I am using. The middleware is the same as above but I am also using apollo as well as serverless-component.

Comment: @MarkG I did a basic test using Next starter `localhost:3000/api/hello` with the `_middleware` in `pages/api/_middleware.js`. It looks like the redirect will trigger if I directly navigate to the api, but will not work if the request is made via code.

Comment: Notice that as of Next version 12.2 the middleware file does not need an underscore and is not nested. See https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/middleware-upgrade-guide.